# Number Theory Proof on Binomial Theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

[I was trying this proof.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFzbs.png)

If $2\le k\le n-2$

$${n\choose k}= {n-2\choose k-2}+2{n-2\choose k-1}+{n-2\choose k}$$

for $n\ge 4$.

It appears that we need to induct on n. But since it is given that 2<=k<=n-2, it appears that if have to also show that the equation holds in this interval of k indicating that there is a need to induct on k too. But how to induct on k? Since, both n and k are restricted to a certain interval, we cannot consider either in general.
I have just started learning about number theory so there might be gaps in my knowledge.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Although induction possible, this is overkill.  This is just a disguised form of the principle behind Pascal's triangle, where every number, except on the ends of the row, is the sum of the two numbers above it.  You simply have to **go back one row**.  Each of the two numbers above it, are themselves the sum of the two numbers above each of them.

Comment: See [Committee by selection assignment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937446/show-by-committee-selection-argument) for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $k$ is restricted by $n-2$ doesn't prevent from using induction. Since the induction is based on the assumption that $k <= n-2$, it will 'stop' when $k$ reaches its maximum.

However, there is no need to use induction here.

Note that in the right wing you have twice $\binom{n-2}{k-1}$.
Hence you can re-write the right wing: $$(\binom{n-2}{k-2}+\binom{n-2}{k-1}) + (\binom{n-2}{k-1}+\binom{n-2}{k})$$
According to one of the basic binomial equations, you can get: $$\binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-1}{k} $$
And using again the same equation you can get:
$$\binom{n}{k}$$

Comment: FYI, the "one of the basic binomial equations" is called [Pascal's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule) (or, as the article states, "Pascal's formula"). Also, welcome to Math SE.

Comment: Thanks! Both for the clarification and for the welcome :)

Comment: Thanks. I was overthinking it :)